# createBrowserRouter pass props to parent component to validate permissions

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**What I'm about to do maybe useless. If the community has anyother solutions please present it to me**

What I'm doing is I need to check each route if the user has access to it. So What I will be doing is if the user doesnt have access to the route/page a--lication redirects to dashboard

user permissions are defined as numbers you can see that in below code

`element: <Register requiredPermissions={[2, 3]} />`

the full code

```
// import AuthRequired from "@/AuthRequired"
import Dashboard from "@/pages/Admin/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Login from "@/pages/Admin/Login/Login";
import Home from "@/pages/Home/Home";

import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthRequired from "./AuthRequired";
import Register from "@/pages/Admin/Register/Register";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    element: <AuthRequired requiredPermissions={[]} />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "admin/dashboard",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: "admin/dashboard/register",
        element: <Register requiredPermissions={[2, 3]} />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

what i need is i need to some how pass the props which [2,3] to AuthRequired.tsx

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { store } from "@/store/store";

interface RequiredPermissionsProps {
  requiredPermissions?: number[]; // Optional array of required permissions
}

function AuthRequired({ requiredPermissions = [] }: RequiredPermissionsProps) {
  const _location = useLocation();

  const {
    auth: { token, user, permissions },
  } = store.getState();

  console.log("requiredPermissions ->", requiredPermissions);

  return (
    <>
      {token && user && permissions && permissions !== "" ? (
        <Outlet />
      ) : (
        <Navigate to="/admin/login" state={{ from: _location }} replace />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default AuthRequired;
```

so inside AuthRequired.tsx i can check for the condition and Output or Redirect

Do you have any solution to do this, or is there anyother way im about to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to compare `state.auth.permissions` against the passed `requiredPermissions` prop I suggest the following refactor of `AuthRequired`.

```
function AuthRequired({ requiredPermissions = [] }: RequiredPermissionsProps) {
  const location = useLocation();

  const { token, user, permissions } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

  console.log({ requiredPermissions });

  const hasPermission = requiredPermissions.length
    ? requiredPermissions.every(
      permission => permissions.includes(permission)
    ) : true;

  const hasAccess = token && user && hasPermission;

  return hasAccess
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/admin/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
}
```

Re-organize and wrap the routes that you are wanting to protect by permissions/roles.

Example:

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
  {
    path: "admin",
    children: [
      { path: "login", element: <Login /> },
      {
        path: "dashboard",
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Dashboard /> },
          ... any other unprotected admin dashboard routes
          {
            element: <AuthRequired requiredPermissions={[2, 3]} />,
            children: [
              { path: "register", element: <Register /> },
              ... any other protected admin dashboard routes
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```